# Hide jquery menu after click function does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSS dropdown menu that is functioning how I want it to except for one part, clicking on one of the submenu items does not close the submenu.

Most people probably don't care about this because each link will take them to a new page, but mine just stays on the same page and calls a javascript function.

Using jquery, I am unable to hide the submenus on click like so:

```
$('.sub li').click(function(){
    $('.sub ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you show your html

Comment: check this demo here  -- https://jsfiddle.net/3r404zf5/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the docs [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question so we could help you.

Comment: @ Darren Sweeney -- [https://jsfiddle.net/w8eLvr4x/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what you need to do is to hide it, but then remove the hard coded styling from the element as this will prevent the hover working:

```
$('.sub li').click(function(){
    $('.sub').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){ // breathing space
        $('.sub').prop('style', '');
    }, 10);
});
```

[Here's a working version fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drqjenfn/)

Comment: It is working in the fiddle. But not working for me.

Comment: Then you must have something else going on that's breaking it - the fiddle works ok as you say - and second time hovering works ok in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The class `.autoclose` is applied to a `<ul>` not a `<li>` so correct the assign class on the html and should work